# Why tableview scroll when insert rows?

Tags: ios, ios7

I'm trying to insert new rows from my Core Data on the bottom of the  tableview, everything works fine, except that my tableview scroll a random rows to the top

My table view has variable height (each rows has different height)

I want that when the user scroll on the bottom of the table view, it load 10 more rows from core data but the scroll must stay on the same

my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row == [_data count] - 1 && !loadingData) {
        loadingData = YES;
        [self loadMoreData];
    }
    //Create Cell
}


-(void)loadMoreData {
    int from = (int)[_data count];

    NSArray *temp = [Functions loadNewDataFrom:from];

    if ([temp count] > 0) {
        [_data addObjectsFromArray:temp];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        loadingData = NO;
    }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I already try allot of solutions on google & stackoverflow and always its the same,
and I'm trying it on iOS 7 simulator 4 inch

Thanks!

Comment: It's almost certainly a mistake to call loadMoreData from cellForRowAtIndexPath...  It will get called N times for N visible rows, and on every scroll, even upwards.

Comment: @danh I think that this " if (indexPath.row == [_data count] - 1 && !loadingData)" prevents to called but once. and not on the top